# Как динамически отправить форму?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

Подскажите как реализовать выход с акк. Есть ссылка и по нажатию отправляется динамически форма, с помощью пост запроса, на указанный url. на указаном url убивается сессия и идет перенаправление на главную страницу. вот код

```
a(href='', onclick="$('<form method=POST action=/logout>').submit(); return false") Выйти
```

на /logout cлед.код

```
exports.post  = function (req, res) {
req.session.destroy();
res.redirect('/');
};
```

но почему вылетает ошибка Form submission canceled because the form is not connected, подскажи те как привязать форму или  может как то реализовать это по другому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте форму частью документа:

`$('<form method=POST action=/logout>').appendTo('body').submit();`